Не понимаю где допустил ошибку в коде
Начинаю изучать язык python. Написал простую задачку, но код срабатывает некорректно. Не понимаю, где ошибка в коде.
Я хотел получить нечетные числа, но никакого ответа перечисления чисел не последовало.
for i in range(1,11):
    if i == 5:
        break
        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue
            print(i)  


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. как задать хороший вопрос 2. пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Приведите код (и описание ошибки) форматированным текстом


Код текстом. 2) У вас там похоже лишняя табуляция у половины кода. Табуляции важны в питоне. Весь код идущий после break попал в первый if и не отработал, потому что отработал break.


Спасибо за разбор, но я не понимаю как убрать лишнюю табуляцию и что значит "код текстом" та как в интернете пишут "Код — это «текст», который составлен на одном из языков программирования." Так как я тока не давно начал изучать язык программирования,  и не до конца  понимаю что к чему.

@MIDASGtnhjd Прямо возьмите и скопируйте ваш код в текстовом виде в ваш вопрос. Вы можете его редактировать. Табуляцию убрать - ну поставьте курсор в начало той строки, где хотите убрать лишние табуляции и/или пробелы и нажимайте Del сколько-то раз. Есть способ проще - выделить фрагмент текста и нажать кажется Ctrl+Tab

как убрать лишнюю табуляцию  - cдвиньте последний блок кода влево.

@CrazyElf Shift+Tab

Зачем такой сложный код? Вы в for'е проверяйте если остаток от деления на 2(% 2) равен 1, выводите i. Всё больше ничего не нужно.

Ничего ты не начал изучать. Начни заново, раз такие вопросы...

если я не ошибаюсь, у вас неверная табуляция
for i in range(1,11):
    if i == 5:
        break
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)

